# Run Android emulator without GUI (headless Android)

Tags: android, android-emulator, adb, headless

How can I run emulator without GUI (headless Android)?

My requirement is to run the headless *Android* on the emulator. Is it correct if I use `ro.config.headless 1`? Or disable *zygote*?

Comment: My requirement is to run the headless Android on the emulator.
Maybe use ro.config.headless 1 ?
or disable zygote?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44900957/android-emulator-in-jenkins/47745530

Comment: @Onik it relates to `Jenkins`, while this is a real-world application for it... here the `user-interface` content tag appears misleading, because the `headless` rules that out.

Answer (score 12):

As of `29.2.11`, you need to use the `-no-window` option instead of the `emulator-headless` binary:

> The binary `emulator-headless` is now retired. Headless builds of the engine are now launched via `emulator -no-window`, thus unifying the previously separate (but similar) paths.

https://androidstudio.googleblog.com/2019/12/emulator-29211-and-amd-hypervisor-12-to.html

Answer (score 8):

Android Emulator 28.1.8 now supports running the emulator in headless mode (`emulator-headless`): https://androidstudio.googleblog.com/2019/02/emulator-2818-canary.html

Answer (score 2):

One of the options to achieve that is to stop `zygote` service when an emulator running. When stopping the `zygote` process (aka `app_process`) all of the system services, that were forked from `zygote` at system boot, shuts down. Only a few native system services will be running. The emulator's display should show the startup logo (or animation).

The steps for stopping `zygote` are as follows:

- `adb shell`
- `su` (*most of emulator images have `/system/xbin/su`*)
- `stop zygote`

After that you can explore how less services are running with `service list`. Critical for Android Runtime services will be stopped, e.g.

```
activity: [] // ActivityManager
package: [] // PackageManager
display: [] // DisplayManager
...
```

To start `zygote` execute:

- `start zygote`

**Note**: with the @CommonsWare's solution you are still going to have `zygote` and most of the *Android* system services running.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing an issue with the emulator not running after building AOSP on my ssh server ubuntu 18.4.

> emulator: WARNING: system partition size adjusted to match image file
> (2562 MB > 800 MB)  QXcbConnection: Could not connect to display
> Aborted (core dumped)

I used `emulator -no-window` and I found the emulator process started.
now I can use ADB to verify AOSP changes