# TextView not always expanding to a second line in TableLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, android-tablelayout

I have an app that is pulling information from a `json` file:

```
{
 "EVENTS": [
        {
            "what": " TABLE-QUIZ",
            "who": "anyone",
            "when": "31st January",
            "where": "ABC HELLO"
        }
    ]    
}
```

When I run the app, sometimes the text in the column `When` is cut off on smaller screens when it goes onto a second line. If the text in the `What` column is too big it will go onto a second line and not get cut off.  Why is the `When` column not going onto the second line while the `What` column is?

[image]

Here is the layout `xml` that I am using:

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:shrinkColumns="*"
android:stretchColumns="*" >

<TableRow
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/what"
        android:layout_width="0px"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/textlines"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textSize="12sp" >

    </TextView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/when"
        android:layout_width="0px"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.65"
        android:background="@drawable/textlines"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textSize="12sp" >
    </TextView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/where"
        android:layout_width="0px"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/textlines"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textSize="12sp" >
    </TextView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/forWho"
        android:layout_width="0px"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/textlines"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textSize="12sp" >
    </TextView>
</TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

EDIT:
If I add:

```
android:minHeight="30dp"
```

to the `TextView` then I can get it to display the two lines, but I am hoping for a solution that will work automatically.

Comment: Hi, Howli! Sorry for disturbing! Do you mind reopening the [4-years-old question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20869067/3290339). There are few alternative answers the question is lacking of. Those answers are worth to be relieved and might be especially helpful for AOSP starters. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you set `TableLayout's width` (parent's width) to `wrap_content`. Setting it to **`match_parent`** like this

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    ...
```

makes `When` column go to the next line without being cut off.

Answer (score 1):

You need to view the full data means add this on Textview

```
android:singleLine="false"
```

Hope this one will helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Change `android:layout_weight` to 1 and `android:layout_width` in all the TextViews to 0dp, so that `layout_weight="1"` property can work.

Hope this helps!

Comment: That does work, but then each column has the same width, I need the `When` column to be smaller than the others.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:shrinkColumns="*"
    android:stretchColumns="*" >

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView41"
            android:text="when"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView42"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="28°C" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView43"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="where" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView44"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="what" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView44"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="for who" />

    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```