# How to Start android service without activity

Tags: android, android-service, android-context

I created an application that contain a `Service` that start from button click of `Activity`.

But I want to create a new application that doing the same as the last one - but don't have any GUI interface => that mean without any `Activity`.

I want to make the application to start on device boot and never stop (until the device is shutdown) .

How to do it ? 
Is there any way ?

Comment: Hi, Yanshof! Sorry for disturbing! Do you mind reopening the [4-years-old question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20869067/3290339). There are few alternative answers the question is lacking of. Those answers are worth to be relieved and might be especially helpful for AOSP starters. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How to do it ?

By using [`Context.startService()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#startService%28android.content.Intent%29) or [`Context.bindService()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#bindService%28android.content.Intent,%20android.content.ServiceConnection,%20int%29) methods.

where `Context` might be `Activity`, `Application`, argument of the `onReceive()` method of `BroadcastReceiver` etc.

Comment: i don't understand - can you please explain

Comment: Pretty much the same as starting an `Activity`. You use the `startActivity()` method of [`Context`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#startActivity%28android.content.Intent%29).

Comment: but the main class is extends BroadcastReceiver not activity ?

Comment: And you have `Context` at your disposal in `onReceive()`, so use it as per the answer.

Comment: I still dont understand - can you please explain

Comment: i still need to extends from Activity in my main class ?

Comment: No! Look at the accepted answer of your previous question. What you have is a `BroadcastReceiver` and `Service` declared in the manifest (no `Activity`). System gets an sms, creates an instance of the receiver passing `Context` as parameter of `onReceive()`. You then use it to whatever you want as per the docs: start a 3d party app's `Activity` with `startActivity()`, start the service of your app with `startService()` etc.