# Android Emulator in Jenkins

Tags: android, jenkins, centos7, headless

I tried to use Android Emulator in Jenkins,
I follow this guide: [Jenkins Plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/android-emulator)

I do it from headless build machines, CentOS.
I tried to create emulator from jenkins like the example

When I try to [do this like the example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XSdLS.png), but with my version, I get this error from the jenkins:

```
PANIC: Broken AVD system path. Check your ANDROID_SDK_ROOT value [/opt/android-sdk_r24.2-linux]!
[android] Emulator did not appear to start; giving up
[android] Stopping Android emulator
$ /opt/android-sdk_r24.2-linux/platform-tools/adb kill-server
Finished: NOT_BUILT
```

I also try to do like the second example, I wrote " android list avd" in my terminal
get :

```
Available Android Virtual Devices:
Name: android-23-emulator
Path: /root/.android/avd/android-23-emulator.avd
Target: Google APIs (Google Inc.)
     Based on Android 4.2.2 (API level 17)
Tag/ABI: default/armeabi-v7a
```

put the name "android-23-emulator" in the AVD name.
And jenkins don't search this in the right folder, got this error:

```
FATAL: /var/lib/jenkins/.android/avd/android-23-emulator.ini (No such file or directory)
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /var/lib/jenkins/.android/avd/android-23-emulator.ini (No such file or directory)
```

When my:

```
ANDROID_AVD_HOME=/root/.android/avd
ANDROID_HOME=/opt/android-sdk_r24.2-linux
ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=/opt/android-sdk_r24.2-linux
```

I will be happy for any help! thanks!

---

Answer (score 0):

In order to run the Android `emulator` on headless Linux, you need to add the following switches:

```
-no-audio -no-window
```

In general, user `jenkins` cannot access `/root` ...

Therefore you need to move over the `$HOME/.android` directory:

```
mv /root/.android /var/lib/jenkins/.android
```

and also the AVD location needs to be adjusted accordingly:

```
export ANDROID_AVD_HOME=/var/lib/jenkins/.android/avd
```