# Is it possible to open an Android emulator headless & have it automatically run an apk?

Tags: android, android-emulator, apk, headless

I have *Android Studio* setup and can run the following command to run it in headless mode (so the window is not showing), but I would like to run it headlessly and have it run an *apk*. How would I go about doing this?

I currently run the following to load my AVD:

```
emulator -avd NexusAVD -no-audio -no-window
```

Answer (score 1):

Executing `emulator -avd AvdName -no-audio -no-window` does not give you "truly" [headless](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52345717/3290339) *Android*, meaning `zygote`, so as most of the system services (incl. *ActivityManager*), will still be running. You can check it with:

```
adb shell
service list
```

That said, you can simply deploy your app from within *Android Studio*, just same as do for none-"headless" emulator. Check that your app has been successfully deployed and is running using:

```
adb shell
ps -e | grep packageName
```