# Can't start emulator in headless mode

Tags: android, android-emulator, adb

I was trying to start `emulator` with the following command.

```
/home/shahrear/Android/Sdk/emulator/emulator -avd Pixel2_API_29 -no-window
```

But I was getting the following errors. Without the `no-window` option it works fine but I need to start it in headless mode.

```
pulseaudio: Failed to initialize PA contextaudio: Could not init `pa' audio driver
E1008 14:00:45.458379787   17283 socket_utils_common_posix.cc:201] check for SO_REUSEPORT: {"created":"@1602144045.458354128","description":"SO_REUSEPORT unavailable on compiling system","file":"/mnt/tmpfs/src/android/emu-master-dev/external/grpc/src/core/lib/iomgr/socket_utils_common_posix.cc","file_line":169}
```

and `adb devices` showing offline

[image]

Comment: [Run Android emulator without GUI (headless Android)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20869067/3290339)

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue with the following 2 commands:

```
echo yes | /bin/Android/Sdk/tools/bin/sdkmanager --licenses
touch /home1/www/.android/repositories.cfg
```

Refer to: [Stuck at ".android/repositories.cfg could not be loaded."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43433542/stuck-at-android-repositories-cfg-could-not-be-loaded)

Plus, you could possibly remove the audio error by specifying `-noaudio`.

For example,

`emulator @Nexus_5X_API_23 -noaudio`

Refer to: https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-commandline